# text moves out of Bootstrap button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap button has some text when i run button text moves outside of button but button is in fixed size
how do i make button responsive

```css
.div{
        float:left;
        height:300px;
        width:22%;
        margin-top:15px;
        margin-left:15px;
        background-color: #e4f2ff;
        position: relative;
    }
    .div img{
        width:100%;
        height:180px;
    }
    .div h1{
        font: 500 1.5em Roboto,Arial,Helvetica !important;
    }
    .div div{
        position: absolute;
        bottom:0;
        width:100%
    }
    .div div a{
        width:50px;
            }
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="div">
                <img src="dual.png"/>
                <h1>Boot From a CD or USB Drive on Any PC</h1>
                <div><a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">Default text here</a></div>
            </div>
```

can someone help me

Comment: Remove `.div div a{width:50px; }`.

Comment: You gave the link a width of 50px. Your button is a link too.

Comment: when i do that my design gets strange is there any methed button strech to full div

Comment: @Sanoj `.div div a{width:100%; }` would make the `a` take up the full width of the `div`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
   .div div .btn-success {
           width: 100%;
       }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/owL9c1gt/1/